# Azure Data Factory: Access web service residing in virtual network

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

My Data Factory (v2) pipeline needs to invoke a REST service that resides in a virtual network deployed to Azure. This is a private network and is not public facing.

There appears to be 2 options:

1. Web Activity: [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-web-activity) mentions it works for public URLs only
2. Web Hook: documentation doesn't mention any such limitations so presumably it does support private access (?)

However, when I attempt to invoke my URL from a Web Hook it fails with Bad Request and no other details.

My strong suspicion is that this is related to accessing a private network from Data Factory, although I can't determine this for sure. The request definitely does not reach my REST service, so the 403 is not coming from there.

Therefore, I have 2 questions:

1. Is it possible for Data Factory Web Hooks to access a private virtual network
2. Is there any way to get more logging on what a Web Hook is doing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it possible for Data Factory Web Hooks to access a private virtual network?

Unfortunately out of the box no. The way data factory works is by invoking pipelie activities on something called **Auto-resolve integration runtime** which is, simply said, a small VM which is provided by MS for you for time required to run the task. This VM is not connect to any VNet and as such can't reach your internal resources.

You would need to use **Self-hosted integration runtime**. Which in essence in a data factory agent running on a Virtual Machine. This was it can be part of your VNet. Data factory will then proxy all requests through that VM.

[image]

While it isn't possible to call Web action over HTTP you can trick it via Lookup action over HTTP dataset with HTTP linked service hosted on that Self hosted integration runtime. I did quick demo for you and tested this using BLOB protected by firewall accepting only VNet traffic.

**linked service**

[image]

**http dataset**

[image]

**Lookup setting**

[image]

[image]

> Is there any way to get more logging on what a Web Hook is doing?

You could try enabling diagnostic settings but I never checked what kind of logs you will get.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, looking at the self-hosted integration runtime details (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-integration-runtime) it looks like it does not support Web Hooks...is that a correct assumption?

Comment: You can trick it by doing Loopup action over HTTP dataset on HTTP linked service which is hosted on self hosted integration runtime. I updated my answer to show this.

Comment: I cannot choose any Http Dataset (http binary, to accept XML responses) with a lookup activity. The integration runtime for me works fine, but then I cannot use it with a web activity for a GET request that returns XML. Do you know if this is achievable?

Comment: I found out I can use the copy activity to GET request XML from a host through a custom integration runtime. Not ideal at all, but that'd do the trick